# How do i rescale feature classes of different scales for intersect analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, vector, intersection

before I intersect 2 feature classes of different scales (e.g. 1:200,000 soil map and 1:25,000 land use map), should I rescale them like how u would resample raster datasets to the same resolution before overlaying them together? If yes, how do I do so in ArcGIS? (I have ArcGIS10.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is georeferenced, you do not need to rescale anything. However, you should be aware that your data sources have different spatial resolution and use a tolerance (20-50 m) to avoid sliver polygons due to this difference.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. yes they are in the same geographic and projected coordinate systems. is the tolerance of 20-50m a general guideline or does it depend on the scales? I actually need to overlay 3 layers and the last one is a shapefile generated from raw vector data created at 1:1,000,000 scale. will that affect things?

Comment: the idea is to take a tlolerance that correspond to the spatial resolution of the "worst" scale. From the paper map scale, the finest detail that you can see is between 0.1 to 0.25 mm, so this gives you a range (just multiply by scale factor)

Comment: just to make sure I understood u correctly: in this case, the worst scale is 1:1,000,000 so I take the tolerance range as 100m (0.1*1000) to 250m (0.25*1000)?

Comment: yes, this it it